# SwiftUIでFirebaseにカスタムオブジェクトを保存する方法について

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

**質問内容**
SwiftUIによるFirestoreへのデータの保存と取得について勉強中です。
カスタムオブジェクトを保存し、取得するテストコードを書いてみましたが、以下のエラーに対処できません。
Firebaseの公式ドキュメントに掲載されているものを使ってみましたが、どのように修正したら良いでしょうか。
エラー内容はコード内にコメントとして追記しています。

**テストコード**

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let savedata = SaveData(savename: "保存名です", savedate: Date(), savedataarray: ["保存するデータA", "保存するデータB", "保存するデータC"], saveint: 123)
    @State private var savedata_fromFirebase = SaveData(savename: "", savedate: Date(), savedataarray: ["初期表示A", "初期表示B", "初期表示C"], saveint: 0)
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Button(action: {
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                do {
                    //Cannot convert value of type 'SaveData' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'
                    //Extraneous argument label 'from:' in call
                    try db.collection("collectionnameY").document("docmentnameY").setData(from: savedata)

                } catch let error {
                    print("Error writing savedata to Firestore: \(error)")
                }
            }){
                Text("カスタムオブジェクトをFirestoreに保存")
                    .border(Color.green, width: 1)
            }
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Button(action: {
                let db = Firestore.firestore()
                let docRef = db.collection("collectionnameY").document("docmentnameY")
                docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    let result = Result {
                      try document?.data(as: SaveData.self)//Argument passed to call that takes no arguments
                    }
                    switch result {
                    case .success(let savedata):
                        if let savedata = savedata {
                            print("SaveData: \(savedata)")
                        } else {
                            print("Document does not exist")
                        }
                    case .failure(let error):
                    print("Error decoding savedata: \(error)")
                    }
                }
            }){
                Text("Firestoreからカスタムオブジェクトを取得")
                .border(Color.green, width: 1)
            }
            //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Text("カスタムオブジェクトを取得したら表示は更新される（以下）")
            Text("\(savedata_fromFirebase.savename!)")
            Text("\(savedata_fromFirebase.savedate!)")
            //Instance method 'appendInterpolation(_:formatter:)' requires that '[String]?' inherit from 'NSObject'
            Text("\(savedata_fromFirebase.savedataarray)")
            Text("\(savedata_fromFirebase.saveint!)")
        }

    }
}

struct SaveData: Codable {
    let savename: String?
    let savedate: Date?
    let savedataarray: [String]?
    let saveint: Int?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case savename
        case savedate
        case savedataarray
        case saveint
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `data(as:)`や`setData(from:)`などのカスタムオブジェクト用のメソッドを使用するには、`FirebaseFirestore-Swift`(`FirebaseFirestore-Swift.beta`かもしれません)が必要です。私はSwift Package Managerを使ったので、podでの設定方法とかはわかりませんが、プロジェクト設定のLibraryに存在するか確認して見てください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。お返事遅くなりました。File→SwiftPackages→AddPackageDependency...から、FirebaseFirestoreSwift-Betaをインストールする方法で試してみたいのですが、podは使用しないのですか？ 　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　アプリをFirebaseに登録する際に、Firebaseに載っている手順に沿って進めると、1.アプリの登録 2.設定ファイルのダウンロード 3.FirebaseSDKの追加...　とガイドされ、CocoaPodsを使ってpodfileを作成しないと次に行けないようになっています。 podを使わない方法で、この先に進めるにはどうされているのでしょうか。　よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `firebase swift package manager`で検索すると、[公式のガイドページ](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/SwiftPackageManager.md)のほか、日本語の解説ページも引っかかるんじゃないかと思います。「CocoaPodsを使ってpodfileを作成」の代わりにSPMでの諸設定を行う形です。

Comment: リンクまでつけていただきありがとうございます。こちらで試してみようと思います。

Comment: swift package managerでfirebaseをインストールし、firestoreの機能を使うために、firebase、firebasefirestore、firebasefirestore-swiftの３つをインストールして、無事実行できました。ありがとうございます。　関連してお聞きしたいのですが、「data(as:)やsetData(from:)などのカスタムオブジェクト用のメソッドを使用するには、FirebaseFirestore-Swiftが必要」という情報は、どこで確認されているのですか？

Comment: 正直に言うと、何かのドキュメントで確認したのではなく、「最初うまくいかないのでそれっぽいものをimportしてみた」と言うところです。これでうまくいくとわかってから読み直すと、あちこちの記事やらカスタムオブジェクトのドキュメントやらで、それが必要と言うのが示唆されていた、と言うところでしょう。さて、できれば時間をとって、無事実行できた解決手順を自己回答として投稿して見てください。同じことでつまづいている人の助けになるでしょう。

Comment: そうだったんですね。いずれにしてもここで質問して正解でした。解決手順については、簡潔ですが自己回答してみました。お時間あるとき、覗いてみてください。

Answer (score 1):

アドバイス頂いた内容から、SwiftUIでカスタムオブジェクトをFirebaseに保存することができるようになりましたので、簡潔に手順をまとめておきます。

1.
XcodeでSwiftUIにチェックを入れて新規プロジェクト作成
ファイル名App.swift　と　ContentView.swift の２つがデフォルトで作成されているはずです。

2.
X-codeで、
→File
→Swift Packages
→Add Package Dependency...
→ URLに　https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git　と入力
→firebase、firebasefirestore、firebasefirestore-swiftの３つをインストール（時間かかります）

3.
Firebaseの公式サイトに行き、アプリを登録（Firebaseで自分のアカウントは作成済の前提で話を進めます）
※公式サイトのガイドに従って登録を進めていくと、CocoaPodsを使ってインストールするようにという説明が出ますが無視して次へで大丈夫です

4.
ファイル名App.swiftを以下のように書き換えます。

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase//追記
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift//追記
import FirebaseFirestore//追記

@main
struct test_Firebase5App: App {
    //追記（ここから）
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    //追記（ここまで）
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

5. 

同様に、firebaseを利用したいファイルに、

```
import Firebase//追記
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift//追記
import FirebaseFirestore
```

を付け足す。

以上です。
ご不明点あればコメントください。（回答者自身も苦戦してよくわかっていない部分も多いので、有益な回答はできないかも知れません。。）
SwiftPackageManagerを使うと、Cocoapodsよりも手順が少なく済み、個人的には便利だと感じました。